# SAPUI5 Pass data from one view to another view

Tags: javascript, routes, sapui5

I am developing of a SAPUI5 application, in my application I need to pass data from one View1 to View2. I follow some sample code from internet but it seems like does not work for me.

The following is my source code

**View1.controller.js**

```
onShoppingCartPressed: function(){
    var viewCartData = {
        "Customer" : SelectedCustomer,
        "Salesman" :  SelectedSalesman,
        "TxnKey" : "TXN1000103"
    };
    this._oRouter.navTo("ViewCarts", viewCartData);
 }
```

**View2.controller.js**

```
    onInit: function () {          
                this._oRouter.getRoute("ViewCarts")
               .attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);  
           },

   _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
                        console.log(oEvent.getParameter("arguments"));
                    },
```

Manifest.json

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "com.accenture.newspage.order.ui.order-ui.view",
            "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
            "transition": "slide",
            "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages",
            "bypassed": {
                "target": [
                    "notFound"
                ]
            },
            "async": true
        },
        "routes": [
            {
              "pattern": "orderDetail/{order}/{layout}",
              "name": "orderDetail",
              "target": [
                "order",
                "orderDetail"
              ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "ViewCarts",
                "name": "ViewCarts",
                "target": "viewCarts"
            }
        ],
        "targets": {
            "worklist": {
                "viewName": "Worklist",
                "viewId": "worklist",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "viewCarts": {
                "viewName": "ViewCart",
                "viewId": "ViewCartPage",
                "viewLevel": 1
            }
        }
    }
```

When I console.log() out the data, it shows me empty data and it does not show the data that I passed from View1.

Comment: What does you manifest look like?

Comment: I have include of my manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have two options here in my option. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Hope this helps.

**Option 1**

*Manifest*

```
 {
    "pattern": "ViewCarts/customer/{Customer}/Salesman/{Salesman}/key/{TxnKey}",
    "name": "ViewCarts",
    "target": "ViewCarts"
}
```

*Sending controller*

```
    onShoppingCartPressed: function(oEvent) {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("viewCarts", {
            Customer: "XXXXXXXXXXXX", // can't be an object
            Salesman: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            TxnKey  : "TXN1000103"
        });
    }
```

*Receiving controller*

```
    onInit: function() {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.getRoute("viewCarts").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
    },

    _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
        var customer = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Customer;
        var salesman = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Salesman;
        var key = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").TxnKey;
    }
```

**Option 2**

*Manifest*

No changes from yours

*Sending controller*

```
    onShoppingCartPressed: function(oEvent) {
        var viewCartData = {
            "Customer": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Salesman": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "TxnKey": "TXN1000103"
        };

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(viewCartData);
        this.getOwnerComponent().setModel(oModel, "viewCartData");
        // OR sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "viewCartData");

        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("viewCarts");
    }
```

*Receiving controller*

```
onInit: function() {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.getRoute("viewCarts").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
    },

    _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel("viewCartData");
        // OR var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("viewCartData");
    }
```

Comment: Don't set your model to the core. Use `this.getOwnerComponent().setModel(...)`. Then you can do `this.getView().getModel("viewCartData")` since all component models are delegated to all views.

Answer (score 1):

For me in most scenarios it's better to use `sessionStorage`.

It allows you to save almost anything (also javascript `Object`) and access it anywhere in webapp.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('myKeyString', 'myString'); //Set value
sessionStorage.getItem('myKeyString');  // Get saved string
sessionStorage.setItem('myObject', JSON.stringify({"key": "value"})); // Save object
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('myObject')); // Get saved object
```