# how to pass the value of one variable from one controller to another controller in sap ui5

Tags: odata, sapui5

i am getting the value of a variable var= ezLinkCard in below code in one of the view controller and want to pass or read this variable value in another view controller.How can i acheive this? your help is appriciated.

```
onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {

    var oView = this.getView();
    var navigationDestinationView = oEvent.getParameter("name");
    if (navigationDestinationView === "initial" || navigationDestinationView === "initial1") {
        var ezLinkCard = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").cardNumber;
        if (ezLinkCard !== undefined && ezLinkCard !== null && ezLinkCard !== "") {
            this.getValidUserId(ezLinkCard);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Please see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328598/sapui5-pass-data-from-one-view-to-another-view/52329227#52329227

Comment: did you get it to work by now?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 options:

- Models
- Event Bus
- Parameter in your Navigation

To know which variant fits best for you and really understanding the conzepts I advice you to do follwoing tutorials for models and navigation parameter:

- https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c
- https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d

For understanding the event bus following question might help (or at least the answer to it):

- [What is the EventBus in SAPUI5 for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187748/what-is-the-eventbus-in-sapui5-for)